# pytest: can I generate test parameters based on fixture (runtime config)?

Tags: pytest

Hopefully this hasn't been asked before, I know that it seems fixtures and parameters are the hardest aspect of pytest to grok..

I'm trying to figure out if its possible to use a fixture as the basis to generate test parameters... (to use the fixture to generate required test parameters, e.g. boundary conditions, at run time)

Something like this..

```
@pytest.fixture
def unit(request):
    """Base dependence"""
    return BuildUnit(request.config.options..)

@pytest.fixture
def something_param_gen(request, unit, option):
    """Resource of interest; configured using an option"""
    return unit.query(option)


@pytest.mark.parameterize('param1,param2', 
    [something_param_gen('optionA'), something_param_gen('optionB')])
def test_something(something, param1, param2):
    """Generate the parameters *specific* for the fixture"""
    assert something.foo() > param1
    assert something.bar() < param2
```

So in `test_something` I want to have params 1 and 2 provided after querying the capabilities of `something` given static options.

I thought about the `pytest_generate_tests(metafunc)` hook except I can't see how I would have access to the `unit` fixture from this context.

I can potentially statically define all the parameters but it would be so much more awesome to do this at run time. Where I could potentially receive a different number of parameters to test or easily manipulate them.

Comment: I see in your `unit` fixture, you are consuming `request.config.options.. ` , you can access the `config` object even from `metafunc (metafunc.config)`, so I believe you can totally move the content of unit fixture to `pytest_generate_tests` and dynamically create your parametrised tests. More info [metafunc config](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html#_pytest.python.Metafunc.config)

Comment: The objective is to be able to generate parameters using a function that will accept fixtures. Is this possible? @Sanju - thanks for your comment and I could do that but then would have to setup (and teardown) the dependencies I need within `pytest_generate_tests` when it would be easier to simply inject the fixtures which already do that :-)

Comment: Short answer is no. You can not use return value of fixture as arguments in pytest.mark.param without any plugins. 

But you can parametrize your fixtures. Once you use parametrized fixture in test, test is parametrized too.

If you don't mind using external pytest plugins, you can use [pytest-lazy-fixture](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-lazy-fixture/). It allows you to use fixture in parametrization.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do exactly what you want. But you can do something pretty similar by parametrizing the static values and providing access to the fixtures that use them.

Something like:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def unit(request):
    return BuildUnit(request.config.options..)

@pytest.fixture
def something_param_gen(unit):
    return unit.query  # note no brackets, because we want to return the query function, not actually call anything (yet)

@pytest.mark.parameterize('param1,param2', ["optionA", "optionB"])
def test_something(something, param1, param2, something_param_gen):
    """Generate the parameters *specific* for the fixture"""

    # something_param_gen is now the return value of the fixture
    # i.e. is `unit.query`, so now we change the comparison

    assert something.foo() > something_param_gen(param1)
    assert something.bar() < something_param_gen(param2)
```